# Ideal location for a massive base?

Tags: terraria

I'm starting to work on making a base, which is based off of this picture below, I have thought seriously about it, and am curious;

(This base was made by Spiritos, which can be found [**here**](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/my-drow-elf-or-dwarven-base-underground.104532/))

[image: Terraria Base]

When someone enters Hardmode, certain enemies arise, including the [**Wraith**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wraith).
Wraiths can go through blocks which can do more harm than needed.

I don't care about worms, but what I **do** care about, is having to constantly be pulling out a sword and be killing enemies...

What kind of location/biome/height can I ensure that **NO** enemies (I can deal with worms) can get in?

I don't want to make that thing, and then have to rebuild it somewhere else when I enter Hardmode. I want the one place where it will be good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I saw some picture of a guy with a hardmode base similar to that but with a lava ring around it, to damage the Wraith. I have no idea how effective it is at keeping them out, worth a shot though.

Comment: FYI, this base was created by Spiritios. Original thread here: http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/my-drow-elf-or-dwarven-base-underground.104532/

Comment: @Dan Ah! Thankyou very much! Will add it in now!

Comment: @Chantola Are you able to find it? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple things to keep in mind when building a large base:

1. NPCs in an area reduce the spawn rate.

   - This means that if you have enough NPCs in your base, you won't have to deal with normal enemy spawns.
2. Enemies cannot spawn in an area if there are player placed walls and the natural walls have been removed.

   - <del>This makes it easier to build bases near the surface since you can remove natural walls much more easily. You could also remove walls in a lower layer, but you would need to remove at least 1 section of wall all the way from the surface to do so</del>. Below 0 depth, there are no walls (except for in Pyramids, Giant Trees, The Dungeon and certain microbiomes), so you can just place walls there to prevent monsters from spawning.
3. Enemies cannot spawn on your screen.

   - This means that if your base is not wider than your screen, enemies will never spawn inside it.
4. There are 4 types of enemies that can pass through walls: Wraiths, Worms, Reapers, and Goblin Sorcerers.

   - The first 3 of these enemies have a maximum distance that they can travel above the ground, so you can prevent them entering your base by having several blocks of empty area around your base.
   - Wraiths, Reapers, and worms are immune to lava, so lining the base with lava does not really help you.
   - Wraiths only spawn on the surface.
   - Reapers only spawn as part of a solar eclipse, which only affects the surface.
   - Goblin Sorcerers only spawn as part of a goblin invasion, which only affects the spawn point.

With that in mind, I would say that the ideal location for such a base is in the cavern layer in the forest biome. This puts you away from the surface (avoiding wraiths and reapers) and away from the spawn (avoiding invasion enemies). If you have enough NPCs in your base, you should not have to worry about worm enemies spawning either. I would also construct the base to not have doors, but rather have player only switches wired to actuators such that a player stepping on the switch opens the "door" and another switch on the other side closes it. Note that you will need to remove all natural walls in the base and replace them with any player placed wall (as noted in #2).

Comment: Re: 2) Walls are not all that common below altitude 0.  Geodes, Mossy caves, Cabins, Ice, Jungle, Corruption, and Dungeon have walls but otherwise build away!  If I want to build slightly above 0', I frequently knock out dirt walls starting from below instead of above.

Comment: I had not actually built anything that needed walls below 0 depth before, but you are right. Looks like below 0 what looks like a wall is actually just the background-- the same as the sky is above ground. I will edit to make that more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Added that too!

Comment: But you missed the rest from my 1st comment... ;)  Walls exist, they are just  in the minority...

Comment: Didn't think it was necessary to list out all of them, so I included them all as "microbiomes". When you say geodes, are you referring to [gemstone caves](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Environment#Gemstone_Cave)?

Comment: #4 - basically that is my conclusion too, put a base underground in a forest biome (cavern or lower) away from spawn point.  To really keep the riff raff out, like he said, build your NPC apartment complex there too!  Plant sunflowers(, and daisies and sing happy songs about bullfrogs and whiskey), too!

Comment: Soo.... With your ending statement of building in the Jungle, should I remove some blocks **around** my base as you stated in #4?

Comment: @FinnRayment If you are building in the jungle, I would remove blocks around the base so that you don't get [Angry Trappers](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angry_Trapper). Although if you have enough NPCs, that should not be a problem.

Comment: @JohnCleaver I'll accept your answer, but **how many** blocks will I need to remove? (In width/height)

Comment: If you build at the cavern layer in the forest biome and you are not concerned about worms, you don't need to have any space around the base. If you are at the surface, you will need at least 7 blocks from the bottom for wraiths and reapers and probably 5 on the sides. For angry trappers (jungle) and worms (cavern), I can't find exact numbers, but I think 10 blocks from other surfaces should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing if you put a ring of lava with 5-6 blocks large, no wraiths will enter! Wraith have 160 hp and lava per hit does 50 hp damage to monsters (plus the buff), so they cant enter! If you have a lava charm and contruct a kind of gate you can safely enter and exit your base. If not you can always build a teleporter to a safe location to exit and enter (using that).

So I'm guessing any location is fine, if you have your ring of lava around it.

Comment: Hmmm... Will that work for all mobs? Interesting...

Comment: Will the lava ring work if the base is larger than your screen?  Just wondering, but I might try to build something like the above picture up in the sky, say in the +200 to +500 feet area.

Comment: @Vanzanz Tell me how it goes. If it works, ill choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: @FinnRayment Started working on a prototype, 90 mins, got a very basic quarter done, so this will take a few days to finish building, then I will try a blood moon and an eclipse just to mess with it.  (Should only see vampire bats at the doors for the eclipse.)

Comment: @Vanzanz Ok. I wish you luck.

Comment: Update: Seems that wraiths are lava immune, but acording to this tutorial, bricks will do the trick, also a 6 block high base will keep them away. So Lava Ring + Brick, mobs free? Dunno, but I will test it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GR_02_PLqs

Comment: Sad news, I build a ball base 310 blocks in diameter with its base at +300 ft according to GPS.  No wraiths enter, but in blood moon, reapers show up, since the base is bigger than my screen, I can't keep them out.  Nothing else appears.  Blood moons do nothing.  I even tried to segregate all sections of the base to valid housing, less the furniture, just to try to keep stuff out.  No dice! :(  Lava surrounds did not work when off screen.